# How to add a win-percentage in a Hash-Map

Tags: java, loops, random, hashmap, percentage

I have a HashMap with an object and an Integer.
I want to loop trough the HashMap Value(The Integer) and select a winner (key), my key is just Strings like "Eva", "Steffen" etc. The percentage to win should be defined how big the integers in the hashmap are.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a `HashMap`, show it to us. If you want a loop, write it, then show it to us. Then, once you've shown what you have, explain exactly what's preventing you from completing it.

Answer (score 1):

Decompose that problem...
For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> lotteryWinners = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
lotteryWinners.add("Eva", 61);
lotteryWinners.add("Steffen", 39);
```

Those numbers have to add up to `100`.
You can put as many people as you want.

Pick a (pseudo)random number from `1` to `100`. There are millions of tutorials on that.

And then...
if this number is between `1` and `61`, the winner is Eva,
if this number is between `62` and `100`, the winner is Steffen.

Comment: how can I do that with numbers over 100?

Comment: Normalize... that is... e.g. if those numbers add up to 564, divide by 5.64.
This would scale to from 1 to 100.

Comment: @PleasurePreck if you are stuck, just ask ;)